# Firefox adding padding to first image in multiple images, although all images have same styling and size

Tags: php, html, css

Hey guys, I have this piece of code:

```
while($uno=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo '<div class="wcapt"><a class="neutral" href="../images.php?id=' . $uno['id'] . '"><img class="pad" src="'. $uno['thumbs'].'" border="0" /></a><br/><center><p>'.$uno['name'].'</p></center></div>';
}
```

And all the images I link to have exactly the same size. Here's the Mainstyles.css

```
div.wcapt
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
    font: 11px/1.4em Arial, sans-serif;
    color: gray; 
    }
img.pad
{
    padding: 5px;
    }
a.neutral
 {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

The problem is that Firefox adds some extra padding to the first image, and only the first image. And this is really annoying. Here's a screenshot of the page:
[image]

Comment: For such a behaviour people will stop help you

Comment: How do I accept them? I just vote? I can't unless I sign up.

Comment: Oh, never mind I got it.

Comment: an online example would be helpful. With a tool like Firebug, it is probably very easy to solve (it shows which elements are causing the padding, and all related CSS rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Firebug and figured out the problem, thanks guys, and I had to answer my question since the answer was in the comments and I can't accept comment answers.

Answer (score 1):

that's why it's recommended to use a ["reset" css](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/)... so you wont have this type of inconsistencies between browsers.

Try using a reset css and if the problem remains then it's not the browsers fault =)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

have you tried targetting the selector more explicitly using..

```
div.wcapt img {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

You could then remove the .pad class completely

Try adding a pseudo selector more information here
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp
Note you need to set the doctype to do this

```
div.wcapt img:first-child {
padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that all the pictures have exactly the same code, so why is it just that pic? I've also tried removing the first pic by using : where id!='1' and the second pic didn't have the padding problem. So what gives?

Comment: @Sam, maybe the name of the picture is to long?

Comment: have you tried investigating the code using firebug, if you inspect the image with firebug it may explain why this is happening